# How to include id in slug using friendly_id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I am using friendly_id gem to have pretty urls in my application.I want an url like:

```
localhost:3000/posts/1/my-first-post
```

I want to do it using the friendly_id gem as i want to use the History module to avoid 404 error.I have tried but can't include the id in the slug.The code i am using is follows:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :pretty_url, use: [:slugged, :history]

    def pretty_url
        "#{id}/#{title}"
    end
end
```

But it is not including the id in the slug.Rather it is using the slug as if only title is used.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` of `Post` is set *after* the entry is saved. `pretty_url` doesn't work because the `id` doesn't exist yet.

You can get this behaviour without using the friendly_id gem by doing:

```
def to_param
  "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember reading somewhere that FriendlyId runs into issues with slashes within your slug function. Try `"#{id}-#{title}"` instead to see if that's the case.

Comment: yes i have also tried that but still the id is not showing.

Comment: Are you seeing "-title" or "title"? If it's the former, then your id mapping could be at flaw. If it's the latter, then....idk to be honest